# Passing Boolean value from c# to angular view

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Here is my simple code:

c#

```
 public bool isAllowed { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isAllowed = false;
    }
```

angular controller

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);    
myApp.value('allowed', <%= isAllowed %>);//myApp.value('allowed', False);

myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function ($scope, allowed) {
    $scope.result = allowed;
}]);
</script>
```

view

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
 <div data-ng-controller="TestController">{{result}}</div>
</body>
```

I end up with
Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined

and

myApp.value('allowed', False);

How can I pass boolean to $scope.result?

Comment: javascript is case sensitive and there is no `False` ... it is `false`

Comment: what are you trying to do is considered a bad practice.. If you need to pass information from c# to client side/angularjs. Consider making an API endpoint through a C# API Controller. Then through angularjs you use a service and you hit the api end point to get the information. The way you have coded it couples front end and backend code  and is usually avoided. C#/ASP.NET is MVC while Angular is MVVM and usually what you only need from C# is just API Controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC by default do convert value `true` to `True` & `false` to `False` while returning model value to view.

In this case your value `False` is considered as JavaScript variable, that's why you are getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined`.(bool value should be either `true`/`false`).

So basically you could either convert it to bool by applying some operation like below.

```
myApp.value('allowed', <%= isAllowed == 'True' %>);
```

Apart from that you had missed `allowed` dependency to inject in DI inline array

```
                     //dependency added here VVVVVVVVVV
myApp.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'allowed', function ($scope, allowed) {
```

Comment: wouldn't be useful to hint the OP that this is not a good practice and mixes back end with front end code and at the same time mixes MVC with MVVM and MPA with SPA architectures?

Comment: @Michail I totally agree with this point..but this situation comes up when, small part of application gets migrated to angular page..but then it become quite challenging to make smaller part of module with different stack by keeping all other module functionality in sync.. And if OP is converting whole page of application then we shouldn't go for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myApp.value('allowed', <%= isAllowed.ToString().ToLower() %>);
```

Comment: it will make it to string `'true'`/`'false'`, which would not be a boolean.